# How to get a free signed secure certificate?

Tags: web-hosting, security-certificate

My web hosting service only provide non-free signed secure certificate.  Is there a way I can get a free one on Internet?

Comment: Sorry but this question is off topic and duplicate of several other [SSL Certs](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=SSL+Free+is%3Aquestion) related questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[StartSSL](https://www.startssl.com/?app=1) provides free ones, trusted by many browsers.